# reverse operation is slow for big list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say i have a list `userlist` of length 100 million.

I am doing reverse of it.

```
%time userlist_r = userlist[::-1]

Wall time: 1.02 s
```

Its taking so much time may be nearly a second.

Can anyone help in this? Please.

Comment: Why do you think an operation on a 100 million item list is going to be faster? 1 second seems reasonable to me. Do you need to recreate the list? Can you just iterate on it in reverse?

Comment: Anything will be slow with a 100 million item list. You're using the wrong tool

Comment: I don't think you can beat this in CPython. Try another language or see if you can change your design to avoid reversing it. You might try PyPy.